# Is there an Int.isWholeNumber() function or something similar?

Tags: c#, int, validation

I need to check if an input is an int or not. Is there a similar function to the String.IsNullOrEmpty(), like an Int.isWholeNumber() function?

Is there a way to validate this inside the `if()` statement only, without having to declare an int before? (As you need to do with TryParse())

**EDIT**
I need to validate an area code (five numbers)

Comment: What do you mean by whole number? Non-Negative?

Comment: And what problem to declare int before? Of course you can write regexp to validate input for only digits, but I think that it will be more expensive than int.TryParse.

Comment: Wikipedia(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) say the term whole number is a little bit ambiguous . What does it mean to you?

Comment: @Aliostad a "whole number" is an integer, bit of a primary school term to be honest.

Comment: Well thanks. I do have an MD and MSc but cannot remember my primary school :)

Comment: @Ben the term does not have a consistent meaning with everyone.

Comment: Yes, the input is a string and I wanted to validate an area code. Edited my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe there's any such method within the BCL, but it's easy to write one (I'm assuming you're really talking about whether a string can be parsed as an integer):

```
public static bool CanParse(string text)
{
    int ignored;
    return int.TryParse(text, out ignored);
}
```

Add overloads accepting `IFormatProvider` values etc as you require them. Assuming this is for validation, you might want to expand it to allow a range of valid values to be specified as well...

If you're doing a lot of custom validation, you may well want to look at the [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Celebrity visit. I guess not marking this as the solution could get me in trouble with SO =)

Answer (score 11):

I gather from your comments that your actual problem is "how do I determine if this string contains a valid Swedish postal code?"  A Swedish postal code is a five digit number not beginning with a zero. If that's the problem you actually have to solve, then **solve that problem**. Rather than trying to convert the string to an integer and then check the integer, I would simply write checks that say:

- is the string five characters long? If not, reject it.
- is the first character of the string 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9? If not, reject it.
- are the second, third, fourth and fifth characters of the string 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9? If not, reject it.

Simple as that. If you're never going to do math on it, don't convert it to an integer in the first place.

This approach will further generalize to more complex forms. Swedish postal codes, I gather, are often written in the form "SE-12 345", that is, with the prefix "SE-" and a space between digits two and three. It's going to be awfully hard to write an integer-validating routine that deals with that format, but writing a string-validating routine is straightforward.

More generally, this illustrates some good advice for writing questions. **Ask a question about the problem you actually must solve**. You assumed a solution -- parse the string as an integer -- and then started asking questions about your assumed solution. That automatically precludes anyone from giving advice that is specific to your real problem. Maybe someone reading this has already developed a library of postal-code validating software; if they have, they'd never know to tell you about it from your original question.

Comment: How do I say this without coming off as a wise guy? My question originated from validating an area code, but my actual question had nothing to do with it. I just wanted to know how to validate an int in one line of code. The DB takes an int of length five only (I didn't design it and don't tend to re-design it either). John's answer is precise and to the point. Not that I don't appreciate your answer and your effort!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by extension methods:

You use

```
bool isNumber = "-1990".IsNumber();
```

Here is code:

```
public static class NumberStringExtension
{

    public static bool IsNumber(this string value)
    {
        int i = 0;
        return int.TryParse(value, out i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that you *can* write everything after the declaration as: `return int.TryParse(value, out i) && i >= 0;`. Whether you view that as more or less readable than the longer form is a personal preference :)

Comment: I have an obsession on extension methods, I cannot resist it :)

Comment: Extension methods work, but why would you have "IsNonNegative" extension of "WholeNumberString" ?

Comment: @JMc I changed the code. It turned out OP was interested in numbers and not non-negative as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Int.TryParse` Or make a custom function.

```
function bool IsNumber(object number)
{
  try
  {
    Convert.ToInt32(number.ToString());
    return true;
  }
  catch
  {
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to throw an exception if the text isn't a number, you might as well just call `int.Parse` to start with... (I also think you missed the bit of the question where the OP said "without having to declare an int before".)

Answer (score 1):

See if int.TryParse gives you an answer, and make sure there's not a decimal point in the input string. (This will give you a false positive if someone enters "1." as the input.)

```
string input;
int ignored;

bool wholeNumber = int.TryParse(input, out ignored) && input.indexOf('.') == -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

int types have to be whole numbers by definition. It would have to be type double, float, or decimal to be a non-whole number. You can always try testing the type of the input.

Or maybe the input is a string? If the input is a string, you could try searching for a '.' or ',' character (depending on the culture). Or you could try parsing as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Since every int is a whole number, this is easy:

```
public static bool IsWholeNumber(int i)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the worst function I have ever seen.  This doesn't even get close to what he wants to do.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to validate it in the if statement you could just do

```
If ( val % 1 > 0)
  //not whole number
```

Comment: This does not answer the user's question.  This does not make sure the value the user inputs is even a number.

Comment: @Ramhound The used never actually stated what type of input it was. My assumption was that the input was a numerical type.  If the input is a numerical type this will in fact work just as asked.