# How to validate a field against a Natural Number?

Tags: c#, validation

How to validate a `TextBox` field against a *Natural Number*? User are restricted to input natural number (e.g. 1,2,3..99999) and if not, a `MessageBox` is shown.

Currently I'm using the following code (assuming the natural number does not go beyond two digits):

```
Regex isPositiveNum2 = new Regex("[1-9]");
Regex isPositiveNum = new Regex("[1-9][1-9]");
if (isPositiveNum.IsMatch(textbox1.Text) == true || 
    isPositiveNum2.IsMatch(textbox1.Text) == true)
{
    /* Do something */
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hey! This is not a Natural Number");
    textbox1.Text = "1";
}
```

This works alright, but I'm sure it's not the best approach. Hope something can suggest something better.

Comment: Sort of the same? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5911449/536610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in [parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx):

```
int.Parse(textbox1.Text) > 0
```

This will throw an exception if `textbox1.Text` can't be parsed, so you may want to use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c846ws90.aspx) instead:

```
int test;
if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out test))
{
  // parse succeeded can check if natural
  if(test > 0)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: it will throw exception if I input something that is not a digit e.g. 123abc

Comment: @KMC - Yes, I have noted that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
int myValue;
if (int.TryParse(mNumTb1.Text, out myValue) && myValue > 0)
{
    //natural
}
else
{
    //not natural
}
```

Comment: You should normally check the value returned by `TryParse` in case the parse did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = -1;
int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out i);

if (i > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;
if (int.TryParse (textbox1.Text, out number) && number >0)
{
    /* Do something */
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hey! This is not a Natural Number");
    textbox1.Text = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the char while user entering:

```
Private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)&&!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //only digit but still allow the user to use control key to Copy&Paste etc. But you need to apply validating with paste text as well
    {
       e.Handled=true;
    }
}
```